# Google Oauth2 login with spring boot using OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

*1.Using spring security oauth2 dependcy.Making successful authentication to google but i cant get refresh token.How do i get refresh token ?ı can get only access token from PrincapalUser object.*

in WebSecurityConfigurer Adapter

2.

```
private OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter() {
        // Creating the filter for "/google/login" url
        OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter oAuth2Filter = new
                OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter(
                "/google/login");
        authorizationCodeResourceDetails.setPreEstablishedRedirectUri("http://localhost:8080/");
        List<String> scopes = authorizationCodeResourceDetails.getScope();
        authorizationCodeResourceDetails.setGrantType("authorization_code");


        // Creating the rest template for getting connected with OAuth service.
        // The configuration parameters will inject while creating the bean.
        OAuth2RestTemplate oAuth2RestTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(authorizationCodeResourceDetails,
                oauth2ClientContext);


        oAuth2Filter.setRestTemplate(oAuth2RestTemplate);


        // setting the token service. It will help for getting the token and
        // user details from the OAuth Service
        String userInfo = resourceServerProperties.getUserInfoUri();
        String clientId = resourceServerProperties.getClientId();

        UserInfoTokenServices tokenService = new UserInfoTokenServices(resourceServerProperties.getUserInfoUri(),
                resourceServerProperties.getClientId());
       // tokenService.setTokenType(DefaultOAuth2AccessToken.REFRESH_TOKEN);


        oAuth2Filter.setTokenServices(tokenService);
//        oAuth2Filter.setTokenServices(defaultToken());


        return oAuth2Filter;
    }
```

Comment: As far as I know the OAuth2 spec says that you need to a make another request using the access token to get refresh token back.

Comment: @tsolakp thanks for comment.Do you know how do i send new request for refresh token to google ?

Answer (score 0):

I added google url param requriments , spring boot application.yml social authentication configuration.